# string.replaceAll(regex,replacement) does not work for some cases

Tags: java

The regular expression I am trying to use is

```
 String re2="((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])";    // YYYYMMDD 1
```

But when I try to replace all occurrences,

```
string.replaceAll(re2,getDate(dayForward,dateFormat));
```

doesn't work. And,

```
matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, getDate(dayForward,dateFormat));
```

only replaces the first occurrence.

Is there any way I can replace all the occurrences?

Comment: With a regex string that complex, it's more likely your bug is in your regex than in matcher or replaceAll. Can you give us more information about what you're trying to replace and what that regex should match against?

Comment: The regex is trying to match "YYYYMMDD 1" ? Why not something more simple like this: (\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\s*\d{1} you can add ? to groups if are optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the result in an other variable:

```
String replaced = string.replaceAll(re2,getDate(dayForward,dateFormat));
```

Otherwise, it means your regex is not right.